# How to write a word from a string. c#

Tags: c#, loops

I've started recently to learn c# and I have a problem.
The problem gives me a sentence and a number and my program has to return that number's word.
Here is what I've made:

```
using System;

string inputData = Console.ReadLine();
string text = inputData;
inputData=Console.ReadLine();
int x = Convert.ToInt32(inputData);
string currentWord = String.Empty;
int wordCount = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; ++i)
{
    if (text[i] == ' ')
    {
        wordCount++; currentWord = String.Empty;
        while (text[i] == ' ') i++;
    }
    if (text[i] != ' ') { currentWord += text[i]; }
    if (wordCount == x) Console.WriteLine(currentWord);
}
Console.Read();
```

For the sentence " I have two pens" and the number 2, the program returns
h
ha
hav
have.
What do I do wrong?

Comment: You can use [String.Split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0) method

Comment: `if (wordCount == x)` will be true for as long as you are iterating the current word. Therefore it will repeatedly write the `currentWord` to output until you reach the next whie space

Comment: You want to output the N-th word right _after_ spotting the following word boundary. Also bear in mind the end of the string is a boundary, too. In addition, consider using a `while` instead a `for`, so that you _do not_ combine index increment in the `for` cycle statement together with an increment in its body. The way you wrote it is far less readable.

Comment: @LazarĐorđević Sure, but then he learns _less_ of the basics.

Comment: @OndrejTucny In my opinion strings can give unnecessary headache if treated like array of chars. It was pain every time I used it like that in C. It is better to learn basics of sorting, dictionaries, trees, ... but that's only my opinion.

Comment: @UnholySheep how do I stop it and get the right output?

Comment: There are multiple possible solutions. The probably smallest change would be to move `Console.WriteLine` after the loop and add a `if (wordCount > x) break;` before `currentWord = String.Empty;`

Comment: @LazarĐorđević unfortunately most ' programming' schools don't allow you to do things that way because the academics don't know how to program.

Comment: @FilipCordas Algorithms and data structures are the very basics. Hence, it is far more important to learn how to construct basic algorithms, than call a `Split` and then wonder why it's slow when you want to return 3rd word out of 10 million in your string.

Comment: @LazarĐorđević Noone said it's _comfortable_ or _easy_. It's basic stuff.

Comment: @OndrejTucny No it's not in fact problems like this lead to people creating bad code because the know the 'basics'. Writing a proper allocation free look ahead parser is not ease and usually it's better to use existing code that solves this problem already.

Comment: @FilipCordas Not really. Unless you know what you are doing and understand what's going on under the hood, misusing LINQ may be a catastrophe to the overall quality of your code, which includes performance and memory efficiency as well. Programming is a craft. Understanding the core concepts of the craft helps you using the advanced tools wisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change it a bit. The problem why it's is giving multiple values, is because you don't terminate the iteration. (break the forloop). I've added some comment to it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // some test data (instead of readline)
        string inputData = " I have two pens";
        string text = inputData;
        inputData = "2";
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(inputData);
        
        string currentWord = String.Empty;
        int wordCount = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            // when the character is a space and the currentWord has something or it was the last character of the text
            // a new word has been found.
            if ((text[i] == ' ' && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentWord)) || i==text.Length-1))
            {
                // when a new word has been found, just check it.
                if (wordCount == x)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(currentWord);
                    // this is where your solution fails.
                    // when the word has been found, break the iteration.
                    break;
                }

                wordCount++;
                currentWord = String.Empty;
            }
            else if (text[i] != ' ')
            {
                currentWord += text[i];
            }
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

---

You could use System.Linq for this, which is much easier.

```
// Split the string on space and create an array.
// Skip some elements and select the first.
var s = text.Split(' ').Skip(x).FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: _“To fix te last word, just add a space, so we always end with a space.”_ — please don't do this.

Comment: I partly agree, I'd rather go for the linq solution, but if you want to fix it with a loop. You'd rather not make it much more unreadable by double checking it after the loop

Comment: I'll give it another thought.

Comment: Adding a single space at the end of a string that may be megabytes long isn't a very efficient technique. I'd rather teach a beginner to understand corner cases and handle them explicitly than prevent them at all. The cost of prevention may be unfortunate.

Comment: True. I'd didn't thought about people might use this also on very large string. I've changed it a bit. Good suggestion.